# How to assign different folders for different ftp users in Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I have a particular requirement that each ftp users should be able to access his own folder only. I have set a default FTP directory and then sub-directories for each users. Each ftp user should be able to access only the folder assigned to him. How accomplish this in Windows server 2008? What does user Isolation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to give them all their own username. Then give all the users read-only rights to the default directory. Give only the authorized user permissions to their subdirectory, and make sure that no one else even has read. If you want, you can even specifically give the deny right to users you don't want to have access to a specific directory.